# Currency selection and price conversion in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating an e-commerce site in ASP.Net 4.0 with C# and I was wondering what is the best way to deal with currency selection? I need to offer GB Pound, Euro and soon other currencies. What is the best way to convert prices displayed on a page on the fly?

I know that I have to have something like a base-rate table, can someone provide an example of this?

Comment: Considering currency conversion rates are constantly changing you might want to look at using an RSS feed.

Comment: do you have an example of doing this i not sure where to being

Comment: Why are you creating a new e-commerce site from scratch? there are a [several .NET open source solutions out there](https://www.google.com/search?q=asp.net+e-commerce+solutions), give your self a slack and use one solution instead where (almost) everything already been thought about and implemented...

Comment: http://rates.fxcm.com/RatesXML   http://www.oanda.com/currency-data/   http://themoneyconverter.com/RSSFeeds.aspx

Answer (score 3):

There is web service called  [xignite](http://www.xignite.com/forex/)

It converts From any currency to any currency .It is always up to date and reliable with every application.But it is not free and you pay for every hit or conversion.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of points to consider:

1. How often do you need to update the currency rates? Hourly, daily, real-time? This will affect your design. I would suggest that daily would be a good place to start.
2. I would pick a 'base' currency - probably GBP in your case - and FX all other currencies to this. For example a simple table (refreshed as per point 1) would contain the target currency (say EUR), the FX rate (to your base currency, today something like 1.201) and the date.
3. Build something that automatically connects to one of the free RSS feeds out there to populate your table (plenty of stuff out there if you do a simple Google search). Alternatively, if rates are updated infrequently then this could be a manual population.
4. Avoid hard-coding anything into the pages themselves, always FX on the fly as required. Note that this will mean keeping an archive of rates in the table.

Comment: can you provide a simple example in c# that goes thru this simon thanks that allows the user to change the symbols on front page

Comment: @David Buckley - Why don't you pick a single currency to always charge, and allow the banks to do the conversion for you, much easier.  Just make it clear that the price is for example $9.99 USD sounds like you have limited skills to begin with and should avoid the solution your trying to use.